# Selenium chrome driver (Java) click() login button doesn't work programmatically but works manually

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I'm just doing some test automation of web UI, specifically this page https://autorefi.capitalone.com/login/

I am locating the lastname, zipcode, ssn input boxes and typing in data (the data here doesn't matter). I am then simply using the locator to click the "Sign In" button. The problem is, everytime I run this within my code (Java) using selenium/chromedriver, I get an error

```
Sorry, we weren't able to log you in. If you continue to see this error, make sure you're using one of our supported browsers.
```

[image]

*The problem is this is not the correct error message.* You can try this yourself by simply opening another tab and entering a random lastname, zipcode, and last 4 digit of SSN. Conversely, if you actually had an offer with Capital one, it would bring up a different page completely. **The point is, the first error message I posted only comes via selenium and is not correct.** The correct error message is:

```
Sorry, it looks like you don't have an offer with Capital one.
```

[image]

I tried sleeping the thread before clicking the button ,because I thought it was maybe clicking it too fast, but it still didn't work. I a bit perplexed why doing the same set of operations manually seems to work, but launching this programmatically through selenium. Can anyone provide any insight here? My code is:

```
 WebElement element;
        WebDriver driver = null;
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        WebDriverManager.getInstance(CHROME).setup();

        // TODO: PROD
        driver.get("https://autorefi.capitalone.com/login/");

        WebElement refiCommonLoginForm = new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.tagName("refi-common-login-form")));
        WebElement shadowRoot1 = expandRootElement(refiCommonLoginForm, driver);

        WebElement refiCommonLastName = shadowRoot1.findElement(By.tagName("refi-common-last-name"));
        WebElement refiCommonLastNameShadowRoot = expandRootElement(refiCommonLastName, driver);

        WebElement refiCommonZip = shadowRoot1.findElement(By.tagName("refi-common-zip"));
        WebElement refiCommonZipShadowRoot = expandRootElement(refiCommonZip, driver);

        WebElement refiCommonLastFourSSN = shadowRoot1.findElement(By.tagName("refi-common-last-four-ssn"));
        WebElement refiCommonLastFourSSNShadowRoot = expandRootElement(refiCommonLastFourSSN, driver);


        refiCommonLastNameShadowRoot.findElement(By.id("loginLastName")).sendKeys("random last name");
        refiCommonZipShadowRoot.findElement(By.id("loginZipCode")).sendKeys("43978");
        refiCommonLastFourSSNShadowRoot.findElement(By.id("loginLastFourSSN")).sendKeys("3483");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        shadowRoot1.findElement(By.tagName("button")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not sure the issue is that, but still possibly this will help.
Instead of clicking the "Sign in" button try submitting it i.e. `shadowRoot1.findElement(By.tagName("button")).submit()`
But I guess the issue here is that this site has some kind of anti bot defense that blocks automated access to it.

Comment: Yeah doesn't look like submit() worked. This is really frustrating , like Selenium exists to automate UI but the pages can block automated access? So annoying

Comment: Yup, there are several technologies developed and used in the last period to prevent bot usages. Google and many others are working on this.